# Pagination without LIMIT

Tags: php, pagination

Few weaks ago I started learning PHP and MVC. So I started making simple project and got stuck at pagination problem.. I need help to find the best solution for pagination in my website. In the most pagination examples I have found, pagination is made with SQL SELECT LIMIT, but in my case it seems not very logical.

I have BooksController:

```
<?php

require 'Database/Connection.php';
require 'Database/QueryBuilder.php';
require 'Database/Book.php';

class BooksController
{
public function index()
{
    $config = require 'config.php';

    $books = new QueryBuilder(Connection::make($config['database']));
    $books = $books->selectAll('books_table');

    require 'views/listofbooks.view.php';
}

public function about()
{
    $config = require 'config.php';

    $books = new QueryBuilder(Connection::make($config['database']));

    $bookId = $_REQUEST['id'];

    $book = $books->selectByID('books_table', $bookId);

    require 'views/aboutbook.view.php';
}

public function search()
{
    $config = require 'config.php';

    $books = new QueryBuilder(Connection::make($config['database']));

    $text = $_REQUEST['search'];

    $books = $books->search('books_table', $text);

    require 'views/listofbooks.view.php';
}
}
```

And ListOfBooks View:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Books</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/styles.css">
 <script src="styles/sorttable.js"></script>
    <script>sorttable.sort_alpha = function(a,b) { return a[0].localeCompare(b[0], 'lt'); }</script>
</head>
<body>
 <form action="/search" name="search" method="GET">
  <input type="text" id="textbox" size="30" name="search" placeholder="Text" required />
        <input type="submit" id="button">
 </form>
 
 <table class="sortable">
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th scope="col">Title</th>
    <th scope="col">Year</th>
    <th scope="col">Author</th>
    <th scope="col">Genre</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
   <?php foreach($books as $book) : ?>
    <tr>
     <td data-label="Title"><a href="/about?id=<?php echo $book->id; ?>"><?php echo $book->Title; ?></a></td>
     <td data-label="Year"><?php echo $book->Year; ?></td>
          <td data-label="Author(s)"><?php echo $book->Author; ?></td>
          <td data-label="Genre"><?php echo $book->Genre; ?></td>
    </tr>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Should I change my recreate my BooksController or there is any other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you haven't mentioned that it has to be done in PHP, in my opinion, the easiest solution to your problem is a simple DataTable plugin. It is javascript (jQuery to be exact, but that is a javascript framework) and it will ease the usage of your server (there will not be one query for each of pagination pages, but one query and javascript will take care of pagination), but increase the use of client's PC. Also, you have filtering, search etc. available for dataTables, but here is the easiest to start with: https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html